# Describe the set $A = \{ 7a +3b: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So in Hammack's "Book of Proof" there is the following example when he introduces the concept of set-builder notation in chapter 1.1.

> Describe the set $A = \{ 7a +3b: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

In which he then proceeds to state the following:

> If n is any integer, then $n = 7n +3(−2n)$, so
> $n = 7a+3b$ where $a = n$ and $b = −2n$. Therefore $n \in A$. We’ve now shown that
> $A$ contains only integers, and also that every integer is an element of $A$.
> Consequently $A = \mathbb{Z}$.

My question is: are the values $a=n$ and $b=-2n$ arbitrary? If not, where did they come from?

Comment: $n$ is an arbitrary integer.  $a= n$ is an integer based on $n$ and $b=-2n$ is an integer based on $n$.  $a$ and $b$ are not arbitrary-- the are strictly defined-- but the basis of their definitions, $n$, is arbitrary.

Comment: I don't think J.W Tanners or Steven Gregory's comments are necessary.  As $a,b$ can be *any* integers then for any integer $n$ we *can* have $a=n$ and we *can* have $b = -2n$.  we dont *have* to but we *can*.  There's nothing stopping us.   so $7(n) + 3(-2n)= n$ *MUST* be in $A$.  Because $a$ is *ALLOWED* to be $n$ and $b$ is *ALLOWED* to be $-2n$.  So we can't *forbid* $7(n)+3(-2n) = n$ from being in $A$.  We *must* allow that for *any* integer $n$ that $n = 7(n) + 3(-2n)\in A$.  (The membership requirements are crystal clear... the anti-$n$ bigots can't keep $n$ out.)

Answer (score 5):

Where did $a=n$ and $b=-2n$ come from?

Well, since $7$ and $3$ are relatively prime,

one can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find a [Bezout relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity);

e.g., $7(1)+3(-2)=1$.  Thus, any integer $n=7(n)+3(-2n)$.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ is arbitrary.

ANd we use the arbtirary $n$ to define $a,b$.  $a, b$ are not arbitrary as they are determined by and are dependent upon $n$.

But the $n$ which determines them is arbitrary.

That is standard and acceptable.

=====

Take 2:  I'm not sure I understand the question but...

The author suspected (s/he actually knew) that $A = \mathbb Z$.  And to prove it s/he takes $n \in \mathbb Z$ is to be an arbitrary integer and s/he wants to prove that $n \in A$.

So she needs to solve $n = 7a + 3b$.  that's one equation and two unknowns.  That should be doable.  In fact there should be infinitely many solutions.

We need $3b = n - 7a$ so $b = \frac {n-7a}3$ so we need to choose $a$ so that $\frac {n-7a}3$ is an integer.  But $7a= 3(2a) + a$ that means $\frac {n-7a}3 = \frac {n-a- 6a}3 = \frac {n-a}3 -2a$ so we just need for $\frac {n-a}3$ to be an integer.

The easiest way to do that is to let $a=n$ then $b = \frac {n-n}3 - 2n=-2n$.

That that's *one* solution.  If $a=n$ and $b =-2n$ then $7a + 3b = 7n +3(-2n) = n$.

But that's only one solution. We could have done let $a=4n$ and then $b=\frac {n-4n}3 - 2*4n = -9n$ and so $7a + 3b = 7*4n +3(-9n) =n$ are we could have let $a = -2n$ so $b = \frac {n-(-2)n}3 -2*(-2n)=n+4n=5n$ and $7a + 3b = 7(-2n)+ 3(5n) = n$. etc.

Is *that* what you were asking?

So anyway.... so for any $n$ we can find $a,b$ where $a=n; b=-2n$ and $7a+3b= 7(n) + 3(-2n) = n\in A$.  So $\mathbb Z \subset A$.

And for any arbitrary $w = 7a + 3b$ for any possible $a$ and $b$ we have $a,b,7,3\in \mathbb Z$ so $w=7a + 3b \in \mathbb Z$ so $A\subset \mathbb Z$.

So $A = \mathbb Z$.